# /exp1/servlet/com.ser1.HelloWorld servlet not available

Tags: java, xml, servlets

Hi created simple `servlet` to print `hello world`. I created `web.xml` too . Still I am getting `error 404 resource not found`.
Here is `servlet` code

```
package com.ser1;
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
public class HelloWorld extends HttpServlet {
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
                HttpServletResponse response)
  throws ServletException, IOException {
           PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
           out.println("Hello World");
 }
}
```

here is `web.xml` file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
 <display-name>exp1</display-name>
 <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
 </welcome-file-list>
 <servlet>
<servlet-name>hi</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>HelloWorld</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>hi</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/hello.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: From the title you mentioned com.ser1.HelloWorld , the class should be in proper package/folder but i cannot see any package statement in your code 2)Remove .html extension in the url mapping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the below set of code in your web.xml,

```
<servlet-name>hi</servlet-name><servlet-class>HelloWorld</servlet-class></servlet>
```

to

```
 <servlet-name>hi</servlet-name><servlet-class>com.ser1.HelloWorld</servlet-class></servlet>
```

You have not mentioned the class name properly in your web.xml